# Check if record exists in Firebase

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to understand how i can do a search in my Firebase database to check if a record exists and if so to grab details under that specific branch.

Currently i can accomplish what i need to by grabbing a specific record and placing it into a textfield and going from there, however i need to do a check on multiple records in the database till a specific record is found and from there load all the details under that branch.

Heres what i am doing currently;

```
    Firebase *ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl: @"https://sizzling-inferno-255.firebaseio.com/"];

//Refer to users entity
Firebase *usersRef = [ref childByAppendingPath: @"id/"];

// Read data and react to changes
[usersRef observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
    NSLog(@"%@ -> %@", snapshot.key, snapshot.value);

    NSDictionary *dict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:snapshot.value];
    NSString *stri=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dict];

    _textview1.text = stri;

    string1 = snapshot.key;
    _label1.text = string1;

}];
```

Feel free to check for yourself using the URL, i only use this for testing anyway.

[I found something close](https://gist.github.com/anantn/4323949) to what i need however it is not in Objective C.

Comment: Do you want to check if the sub-url `sizzleing-inferno-255` exists or what?

Comment: no i want to check if a record inside of sizzling-inferno-255 exists, just by naming it within a textfield.

Comment: Why don't you enumerate all the snapshot.key s in a NSMutableArray and then check if the text inserted by the user is contained in the array? (You may want to check equality with `stringEquals`, I don't know if the function `containsObject` may compare memory address aka class instances instead of string value)

Comment: @BlackBox sorry i made a mistake in the code i added, fixed it now. And snapshot.key only grabs id.

Comment: Why don't you just query for the thing you are looking for - if it exists the query will return the node in question, if it doesn't it will return null. Here's how to do it [Object Exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35486628/querying-for-existing-nodes-in-firebase-is-returning-null/35490527#35490527)

Comment: @Jay i just started firebase can you show me an example

Comment: Click the link in my comment and it's all there!

Comment: @Jay i want to enter the record name n a textfield and then have it search the database?

Comment: Right. The code in the link does exactly that - in this statement:  queryEqualToValue:@"thing you want to search for goes here"]; and the path you want to search would go in the ref statement.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as a duplicate. The answer Jay linked contains the exact code you need: `queryOrderedByKey` and `queryEqualToValue`.

Comment: @Jay thanks for the help also yes it does seem to be a duplicate didn't seem to find it before when is searched for this answer.

Comment: @Jay i still get an error on FQuery. Any idea why this is?

Comment: 'an error' is a bit vague. I would suggest taking your new code and creating a new question since a query is not part of this question and there's not way  to tell what the issue is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm new in firebase, but I've been working too much on the new version.

Is `Record` the name of your `key` inside of `sizzling-inferno-255`? So if it is. In this new version you can retrieve some info by:

```
FIRDatabaseReference *usersRef = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];

[[[[usersRef child:@"results"] child:@"sizzleing-inferno-255"] child:@"record"] observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {

    NSString *record = snapshot.value;
    if(record.length > 0) {
        // Yes! there is a record.
    }

}
```

Is that what you want? Let me know.

Comment: when i use this i just get an error no visible @interface for 'firebase' declares the selector 'child'

Comment: I edited my answer, that's because to get the reference in the new firebase is little different. Are you using the new version? If not check it out https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#prerequisites

Comment: This is not a query. It's attaching an observer to a node, which returns all of the data in that node ( possible multiple child nodes ) and then awaiting any events within that node. The OP was looking for data at a specific node. As a side note, this code will also fail if more than one node is returned in the snapshot as snapshot.value would be a dictionary which cannot be assigned to a NSString. You would need to iterate over the child nodes with a *for child in snapshot.children*